# Executiung performant SQL queries equivalent to "nested deletes"

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, common-table-expression

Consider the following ERD for `Order`, `Item` and `Article` entities:

[image: ERD for Order, Item and Article entities]

I'd like to delete `Orders` satisfying a **complex condition**, and then delete `Items` associated to those `Orders`, and finally delete `Articles` associated with those `Items`.

Cascade deleting from `Orders` to `Items` is possible as `Order` is a parent of `Item`. But cascade deleting from `Item` to `Article` isn't possible as `Item` is not a parent of `Article`. Setting up a trigger is also not an option, since in general I don't want to delete the `Article` whenever an `Item` is removed - it should only happen in the context of this query.

I'm working with PostgreSQL, which supports `DELETE ... RETURNING` statements. Unfortunatly, the result **cannot** be nested like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM articles WHERE id IN
  (DELETE FROM items WHERE order_id IN
    (DELETE FROM orders WHERE complex_condition RETURNING id)
  RETURNING article_id)
```

What is the most efficient way to execute all three delete statements? Each table contains tens of millions of records, and the `complex_condition` is the most time-consuming part, so I prefer not to execute it more than once.

One idea I have is to create a temporary table like this:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE id_of_order_to_be_deleted
AS
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT id FROM orders WHERE complex_condition)
SELECT *
FROM cte1;
```

And then use it to delete `Orders` and `Items`. This way, `complex_condition` is only evaluated once. But I think this is an overkill, and there should be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result *can* be nested using a data modifying CTE:

```
with deleted_orders as (
  DELETE FROM orders 
  WHERE complex_condition 
  RETURNING id
), deleted_items as (
  DELETE FROM items 
  WHERE order_id IN (select id from deleted_orders)
  returning article_id
)
DELETE FROM articles 
WHERE id IN (select article_id from deleted_items);
```

You might want to try `where exists` condition  as an alternative - sometimes those are faster than `IN` conditions.